# Passing json result to view in Play/Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

Model -

```
case class Renting(name: String, pets: Int)
case class Resident(renting: List[Renting])
case class Location(residents: List[Resident])
```

View -

```
@(jsonResults: List[Renting])

@jsonResults.map { json =>
  Name: @json.name
  Pets: @json.pets
}
```

Controller -

```
val json: JsValue = Json.obj(
  "location" -> Json.obj(
    "residents" -> Json.arr(
      Json.obj(
        "renting" -> Json.arr(
          Json.obj(
            "name" -> "John Doe",
            "pets" -> 2
          ),
          Json.obj(
            "name" -> "Jane Smith",
            "pets" -> 1
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

implicit val rentingFormat = Json.format[Renting]
implicit val residentFormat = Json.format[Resident]
implicit val locationFormat = Json.format[Location]

(json \ "location").validate[Location] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[Location] => {
    val location: Location = s.get
    /* Something happens here that converts Location to List[Renting] */
    Ok(views.html.index(location))
  }
  case e: JsError => Ok(JsError.toFlatJson(e))
}
```

Based on the `s.get.toString` output, it seems that the json is being properly traversed; however, I need to change the type from `Location` to `List[Renting]` so that I can pass the result into the view.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should check the type of `jsonResults` and if that matches the type you  take in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by getting the first value from the list using head.  See below -

```
(json \ "location").validate[Location] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[Location] =>
    val renters = s.get.residents.head.renting
    Ok(views.html.index(renters))
  case e: JsError => Ok(JsError.toFlatJson(e))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of jsonResults will not be "List[..]", since the match-statement does not always return a list in your case:

```
val jsonResults = (json \ "location").validate[Location] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[Location] => s.get
  case e: JsError => JsError.toFlatJson(e)
}
```

Make sure your code returns a list by changing the JsError-case accordingly. Also make sure the json-validator returns a list.

```
val jsonResults = (json \ "location").validate[Location] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[Location] => s.get
  case e: JsError => Nil
}
```

Comment: Good point on the error handling.  I modified the suggested implementation slightly so that I can still return the error message.  I understand that I have to convert Location to a list, but I'm having difficulty understanding how I can do that.  Furthermore, I actually need a list of Renting, not of Location and I am not able to change the `.validate[Location]` since it is used for json traversing.

Comment: You can use the map-function on your list in order to convert it. More information: http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/